# Data binding fails to change values for custom control inside GridView inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, aspxgridview

I am creating a `GridView` inside an `UpdatePanel` like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />

<div id="masterHistoryDialog" style="display: none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="historyRepeater" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="historyRepeater" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="false" PagerSettings-NextPageText="Next" PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="Previous" PageSize="4" OnPageIndexChanging="historyRepeater_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <uc:CustomCalendarControl ChangeID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item1") %>' ScheduleID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item2") %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The `PageIndexChanging` event fires as expected, calling the following event handler:

```
Protected Sub historyRepeater_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    historyRepeater.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    historyRepeater.DataSource = GetSchedules()
    historyRepeater.DataBind()
End Sub
```

`CustomCalendarControl` is a custom control.

I confirmed that `GetSchedules` is, in fact, getting my entire data set.

I page the data and have 4 custom controls per page (total of 20 items on 5 pages). The first page works correctly. However, when I try to navigate to one of the other pages, the initialization of the custom control fails because it's not getting the actual values of `ChangeID` or `ScheduleID` - they're always 0.

It fails when I do the call to `DataBind()` because initialization of the custom control depends on `ChangeID` and `ScheduleID` being actual IDs.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has to do at which moment the nested User Controls populate its client side content. This happens first for the Control and then the GridView, so the UserControl has already been build before the values of `ChangeID` and `ScheduleID` are set.

One way to solved this is to manually call the building of the Control from the Parent.

First, modify the UserControl so that it has a public function to properly display the values

```
public string ChangeID { get; set; }
public string ScheduleID { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setUCValues();
}

public void setUCValues()
{
    Label1.Text = ChangeID;
    Label2.Text = ScheduleID;
}


Public Property ChangeID As String
    Get
    End Get
    Set
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ScheduleID As String
    Get
    End Get
    Set
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    setUCValues
End Sub

Public Sub setUCValues()
    Label1.Text = ChangeID
    Label2.Text = ScheduleID
End Sub
```

Next, add an `ID` to the UserControl in the GridView

```
<uc:CustomCalendarControl ID="calendarControl" runat="server" ChangeID=
```

Then in the PageIndexChanging, loop all the rows and call the function

```
protected void historyRepeater_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    //databinding

    foreach (GridViewRow row in historyRepeater.Rows)
    {
        WebUserControl1 control = row.FindControl("calendarControl") as WebUserControl1;
        control.setUCValues();
    }
}


Protected Sub historyRepeater_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    'databinding

    For Each row As GridViewRow In historyRepeater.Rows
        Dim control As WebUserControl1 = CType(row.FindControl("calendarControl"),WebUserControl1)
        control.setUCValues
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the `DataBind()` call succeed?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Is there a different way to approach it?

Comment: Databinding succeeds. It the page life cycle that is causing you problems. Page_Load of the UserControl is triggered first, then the `PageIndexChanging` event. There in lies your problem.